# Create a Lock Function for DataClass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a simple `dataclass` to track a status of my switch like this

```py
@dataclass
class status:
    switch: bool = False
```

This class is used by two threads so I would like to implement a logic to `lock` the `switch` variable change while other thread changing the `switch` value.

something like

```py
@dataclass
class status:
    lock: bool = False
    switch: bool = False
    
    def setattr(self, val):
        if self.lock is not False:
            self.switch = val
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to set some logic like this. Something where I do not need to call the method above to check `lock` on change `switch` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the existing "Lock".  e.g. in the [Threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire).  You "acquire" the lock when you want one thread to have it and use the locked resource.  When another thread tries to acquire the lock it will block until the first thread releases it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to implement lock from threading module if I'm using one thread created by the module and the second one is just main thread created by the program with while loop?